# UIScrollView Content Offset automatically being reset

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, contentoffset

Today I came across a strange problem I have resolved that issue but yes I don't know why that issue came. The scenario is as below

I have a scrollView for which I am setting its content offset by

```
 //scroll the scroll view to sales lead text field.
 [self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,800) animated:YES];
```

But scroll view delegate first set its offset to 800 then 48 and then 28 i.e in non-scrolled position for the form.

But if I set it 75 or any other number like 80 90 or even 100 its working fine. Also I am using

```
[self.textField becomesFirstResponder];
```

in both situation. Why this happens why 800 is not working and 75 worked.

Then scroll view content size is (320,1010).

Code:

```
         //show editable textfield.
         self.salesLeadNameTextField.text=@"";
         [self.salesLeadNameTextField setEnabled:YES];
         [self.salesLeadNameTextField setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
         [self.salesLeadNameTextField becomeFirstResponder];

         //scroll the scroll view to sales lead text field.
         [self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,75) animated:YES];
```

Comment: Are you using autolayout ?

Comment: without code how can we guess your problem?

Comment: @DharmbirChoudhary no I am not using auto layout.

Comment: @sunny I think I have shared the needed code but yes If you want more code than I will edit the ques.

Comment: What do you mean by "delegate first set its offset to 800 then 48 and then 28" ?

Comment: I just NsLog the current offset in scrollview didScroll method. It first print (0,800) then (0, 48) and then (0,28) as the offset for the scrollview.